# Something is went wrong when im sending a created Packet with boost::asio to a Minecraft Client

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, network-protocols, bytebuffer

> **Goal** and **Instruction** to the Protocol about **Notchian** Communication

I have a Server Application that uses **boost::asio's** asynchronous read/write Functions to communicate with connecting **Notchian** Clients. So far so good I read the [Documented Website](https://wiki.vg/Main_Page) and only wrote a **[Status Handshake Packet](https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Response)**. In **Minecraft** you can get those **Packets** at each **Notchian** Server. These Packets do use specific [Data Types](https://wiki.vg/Data_types). My Server is just sending a **String** as a **Json Response** to the **Client**.

> **Code Section** | How I wrote the **ByteBuffer**

```cpp
typedef unsigned char byte; /* Sending unsigned bytes */
class LBuffer {
    std::vector<byte> buf;

public:
    std::vector<byte>& getBuf() {
        return buf;
    }

    void write(byte data) {
        buf.push_back(data);
    }

    void writeInt(int32_t data) {
        buf.push_back(data >> 24);
        buf.push_back((data << 8) >> 24);
        buf.push_back((data << 16) >> 24);
        buf.push_back((data << 24) >> 24);
    }

    void writeString(std::string data) {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(buf));
    }
};
```

> **Code Section** | How I wrote the Packet to the Buffer

```cpp
LBuffer createHandshakeStatusResponsePacket() {
    LBuffer buffer;
    buffer.write(0x00);
    buffer.writeString("{{\"version\":{\"name\":\"1.8.7\",\"protocol\":47},\"players\":{\"max\":100,\"online\":5,\"sample\":[{\"name\":\"thinkofdeath\",\"id\":\"4566e69f-c907-48ee-8d71-d7ba5aa00d20\"}]},\"description\":{\"text\":\"Helloworld\"}}}");
    return buffer;
}
```

> **Code Section** | Writing Server with the ResponseBuf

```cpp
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    tcp::acceptor a(svc);
    a.open(tcp::v4());
    a.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    a.bind({ {}, 6767 });
    a.listen(5);

    using session = std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>;

    std::function<void()>        doAccept;
    std::function<void(session)> doSession;


    doSession = [&](session s) {

        auto buf = std::make_shared<std::vector<byte>>(1024);
        
        s->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(*buf), [&, s, buf](error_code ec, size_t bytes) {

            if (ec)
                std::cerr << "read failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            else {

                /*
                   As you see I dont read the Request from the Client..
                   But thats not relevant when I just want to send the Data
                   to receive it's Motd and so on..
                */
                if (ec)
                    std::cerr << "endpoint failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                else {

                    std::vector<byte> responseBuf = createHandshakeStatusResponsePacket().getBuf();

                    async_write(*s, boost::asio::buffer(responseBuf), [&, s, buf](error_code ec, size_t) {
                        if (ec) std::cerr << "write failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                    });

                }

                doSession(s);
            }

        });
    };

    doAccept = [&] {
        auto s = std::make_shared<session::element_type>(svc);

        a.async_accept(*s, [&, s](error_code ec) {
            if (ec)
                std::cerr << "accept failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            else {
                doSession(s);
                doAccept();
            }
        });
    };

    doAccept();
    svc.run();
}
```

> **Results** and **Problems**

When my **Notchian** Client reads the Packet that I sent as Response from the **Server**, it's giving me without any Delay this Result here:

> Can't connect to Server

The Log from my **Notchian** Client said:

> [04:42:54] [Client thread/ERROR]: Can't ping 127.0.0.1:6767: Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 123

But how can it be the packetId 123 ? Because I'm sending the PacketId 0 at first.

> **Declaration**

**Notchian**: Typically Software written from Notch ( so I grabbed it up )

**ByteBuffer**: Sending Bytes in a specific order.

I do hope for Tips and Solutions,
thanks

Comment: Note that according to http://www.asciitable.com ASCII character 123 is { (i.e. the left-curly-brace character).  My guess is that the server is interpreting the curly brace you send at the start of your JSON string as part of the packet ID.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner This was really helpful! But now I'm thinking how I could fix that. I'm looking up to the wiki.vg Page! Eventually I can find any Solution to that problem.

Comment: I suggest capturing a "known good" packet (either via WireShark or similar, or by pointing a known-working client at a server that has been instrumented to print out hex dumps of the packets it receives); then eyeball-compare that known-good packet's bytes against the bytes of the packet your program is sending.  If the packets are different (especially in the first few bytes), then presumably your program's packet is wrong and the known-good packet is correct.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I captured the known-good packet but it's not capturing my Response to the Notchian Client. I filtered the tcp port to 25565. So how could I most suitable compare it?

Comment: Have your program print out the packet's bytes when it sends them:  `for (size_t j=0; j<buf.size(); j++) printf("%02x ", buf[j]); printf("\n");`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I have now the bytes from my packet. But when I do compare it with another Server response, I don't know what I need to do now. The good-known Packet from the another Server response has at first 0x00 then it goes with another 30 bytes with other Hexadecimals. Here is a [Screen](https://imgur.com/a/h7cJ3WU). Left is the good-known Packet and the right side is the wrong Packet

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I got it, I need to write a Non Compressed Packet at first. But for that I do need a VarInt. But how could I write that? Because at the [Documentation](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Data_types) Page it's writing with three of some bitshift characters "value >>>= 7".